# Create .so library from .h and cpp libraries, to be used with python on raspberry pi

Tags: python, c++, arduino, shared-libraries, arduino-ide

How could I create a .so library since I have several .h and .cpp files?

I have an algorithm that works to be able to write/read RFID cards, but I only have this algorithm working with **Arduino**. So my interest is that the libraries that I have in .h and .cpp of Arduino make them work in python. I had read in an article that I could make a cython file and then pass that file to the .so library to be able to use this .so in raspberry and invoke the methods from python.

But I have also seen that there are many ways to achieve this, but it is not very clear to me. Can someone advise me or help me with their expertise?

These are the libraries that I have working on Arduino, there are 8:

[Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfelj.png)

Comment: Search key: *Cross Compiler*. Unfortunately Arduino uses its own custom standard library that probably will not port well at all.

Comment: the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) is a probably a good place to start

Comment: @user4581301 probably easier for a beginner to just build on the pi rather than having to work out cross compilers

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block and/or error message in the body of question instead of a screenshot. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9170226) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Interfacing C/C++ code to python is not a trivial task. There are several approaches to this:

- [Extend](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) python by writing a compiled python module (most of it covers C but there is also a small section about C++). This requires you to write a lot of additional C/C++ code using python class structures and functions from the `Python.h` header.
- Use the a python foreign function interface like [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) or the [cffi library](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This requires you to write a lot of additional python code to interface a compiled shared library (.so). I believe you have to use a shared library with C Abi functions, so you might have to rewrite C wrapper functions around your C++ classes.
- Use an interface compiler like for example [swig](https://www.swig.org/exec.html) to automatically create the connection between C++ and python. This requires you to learn how to use swig, which may or may not be a challenge of it's own.

All these methods only work if you manage to **compile your C++ code to run on the raspberry pi**. For this you need to keep the following in mind:

- Arduino programs use non-standard libraries. It is not only about the header files, that are shown in the question, but also about the libraries themselves. You need a way to provide those libraries for the raspberry pi.
- A program on the raspberry pi runs on an operating system whereas arduino programs run directly on the micro controller. You cannot access the hardware the same way in both systems. On Linux you have to look for device drivers etc. to support your hardware (depending on how it is connected to the pi).

There might be cross compilers (things that do all the right stuff automatically), but I did not manage to find one.

In conclusion I would say that it is probably easier and more interesting and educational to rewrite the algorithm with standard C++ directly on the raspberry pi. Grab yourself a library like [libnfc](https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc) which you should be able to install directly form the raspbian package manager read the documentation and with a little bit of luck it should work out of the box (if Linux ships with all the correct drivers for your RFID card).

There is also [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/95051) answer to a similar question on the raspberry pi forum which says roughly the same about C++ cross compiling as I did, but does not provide alternatives or additional information.

Good luck with your project.